# Cannot get code coverage with Cypress + Istanbul

Tags: angular, cypress, istanbul, nyc

I tried setting up code coverage in an **Angular 8** project using **Cypress** and **istanbul** **nyc**.

I managed to get the code instrumented (the global variable `__coverage__` is properly set) :

[image]

and the coverage file generated in `.nyc_output` after running `cypress:open`

[image]

But the generated coverage report is empty:

```
$ cat coverage/coverage-final.json
{}
```

Same result when I execute the command:

```
$ npx nyc report --report-dir ./coverage --temp-dir .nyc_output --reporter=text
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |        0 |        0 |        0 |        0 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Here is my package.json devDependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.3",
  "@angular-devkit/build-optimizer": "^0.803.3",
  "@angular/cli": "^8.3.3",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.2.5",
  "@angular/language-service": "8.2.5",
  "@briebug/cypress-schematic": "^2.0.0",
  "@cypress/code-coverage": "^1.10.1",
  "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "^4.1.0",
  "@istanbuljs/nyc-config-typescript": "^0.1.3",
  "@types/jasmine": "^3.4.0",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
  "@types/node": "^12.7.4",
  "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^5.2.0",
  "codelyzer": "^5.1.0",
  "cypress": "^3.4.1",
  "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^3.0.1",
  "istanbul-lib-coverage": "^2.0.5",
  "jasmine-core": "^3.4.0",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
  "karma": "^4.3.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
  "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.0",
  "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
  "mochawesome": "^4.1.0",
  "ngx-build-plus": "^8.1.4",
  "nyc": "^14.1.1",
  "protractor": "^5.4.2",
  "protractor-html-reporter-2": "^1.0.4",
  "protractor-http-client": "^1.0.4",
  "source-map-support": "^0.5.13",
  "ts-node": "^8.3.0",
  "tslib": "^1.10.0",
  "tslint": "^5.19.0",
  "typescript": "3.5.3"
}
```

And my `.nycrc.json`:

```
{
    "cache": false,
    "extension": [
      ".ts",
      ".tsx"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "**/*.d.ts",
      "coverage/**",
      "packages/*/test/**",
      "test/**",
      "test{,-*}.ts",
      "**/*{.,-}{test,spec}.ts",
      "**/__tests__/**",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "all": true,
    "check-coverage": true,
    "require": [
      "ts-node/register"
    ],
    "temp-directory": ".nyc_output",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "instrument": false,
    "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"]
}
```

Comment: Do you have this code in Support file?

// cypress/support/index.js
import '@cypress/code-coverage/support'

Comment: @N.. nope sorry

Comment: sorry i misunderstood the question (saw it before it was edited). yes I do have the support and plugin files modified, you can see that the tasks are executed (resetCoverage, combineCoverage, coverageReport)

Comment: the problem is NYC not generating the correct output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be an issue in `nyc` when `excludeAfterRemap` is true.

setting it to false fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here is details description step by step.
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/code-coverage.html#E2E-code-coverage

***I think you are missing code-coverage/support file in index.js***  Please do follow change and run. I think you should be good.

```
    // cypress/support/index.js
       import '@cypress/code-coverage/support'

   // cypress/plugins/index.js   
      module.exports = (on, config) => {
      on('task', require('@cypress/code-coverage/task'))}
```

When you run the Cypress tests now, you should see a few commands after the tests finish. We have highlighted these commands using a green rectangle below.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I do however have the commands as you can see in the question (first screenshot)

Comment: Another thing I missed which is necessary is - return the config. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/code-coverage#Install-the-plugin
module.exports = (on, config) => {require('@cypress/code-coverage/task')(on, config); /*other stuff;*/ return config;};

Comment: There is another hidden problem. I'm using typescript. I realised in one of my examples my first page - src/index.js was extension .js. For a day I couldn't figure out why my coverage wasn't being rendered. When I changed index.js to index.tsx the coverage was then rendred.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my advice:

1. First, make sure your tests are running against your local serve instance.

   Example: `ng serve --configuration=demo & cypress run --headed ...`
2. In my experience the `.nycrc.json` is not really needed.
3. The end of your package.json needs this:

"nyc": {
"report-dir": "coverage-e2e"
}

4. Babel is not required; not everyone uses it.  Instead of Babel, a Webpack build config would also work: `./cypress/coverage.webpack.js`

Finally, you should know:

You can instrument your server and then generate a report with these commands:

```
## first, instrument your server locally
nyc --silent ng serve

{ then manually test your app or run automation against it }

## then generate your report from the json files that were generated above
nyc report --reporter html --reporter text  --report-dir ./cov-e2e/summary
```

Answer (score 1):

With @cypress/code-coverage, you have to know that the plugin does not instrument your code. You can use instanbul for that purpose.
There is for example, this plugin [babel-plugin-istanbul](https://github.com/istanbuljs/babel-plugin-istanbul) that can help you achieve it.

if you are already using babel, you need to add the plugin to your .babelrc as follow:

```
{
  "plugins": ["istanbul"]
}
```

For more info check https://github.com/cypress-io/code-coverage#instrument-your-application

Comment: Not true, you don't have to use babel to do this.  Answer is misleading.

Comment: Hey @djangofan, I updated my answer. Thank you for pointing it out.