# Cypress e2e test coverage empty

Tags: reactjs, code-coverage, cypress, e2e

I am using Cypress in my react app for integration test. I am facing coverage related problem, coverage report is showing blank.
[image]

[image]

seems like code is not istrumented properly. can someone help me to figure what's wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: React seems to be the easiest to instrument. I presume you've already seen [@cypress/code-coverage](https://github.com/cypress-io/code-coverage). For React (running React Scripts) you need [instrument-cra](https://github.com/cypress-io/instrument-cra)

Comment: @BarmyFotheringay-Phipps Yes I have already used @cypress/code-coverage. but my app is using React Scripts version 2 so facing problems with instrument-cra.

Comment: You are using React Scripts v2 but also react-hooks? Sounds like a potential conflict just within the React libraries. Why don't you update CRA?

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the cypress guide https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/code-coverage and still not working, you may need to add the option `--exclude-after-remap=false` to your command, for example  `npx nyc report --reporter=text-summary --exclude-after-remap=false`. You can see they mention that here https://bestofjs.org/projects/istanbul undeer the section 'Source-Map support for pre-instrumented codebases'

> If you are using nyc with a project that pre-instruments its code, run nyc with the configuration option --exclude-after-remap set to false. Otherwise nyc's reports will exclude any files that source-maps remap to folders covered under exclude rules.